# Running a WOL PowerShell script through a batch file

Tags: windows, powershell, batch-file

I am trying to run a PowerShell script through a batch file. I want to do this because I want to have my echo to be able to turn on my computer. (there are probably easier ways to send a WOL request from a echo, but I want to do it through PowerShell for learning purposes)

For the WOL command I have this (I do have the correct values for the dashes, I just don't want to show them):

```
Send-WOL -mac ------- -ip --------
```

Then my .bat file contains this:

```
@ECHO OFF
SET ThisScriptsDirectory=%~dp0
SET PowerShellScriptPath=%ThisScriptsDirectory%script.ps1
PowerShell -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command "& '%PowerShellScriptPath%'";
pause
```

Now when I run the .bat file I would get this error:

```
Send-WOL : The term 'Send-WOL' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet,
function, script file or operable program. Check the spelling of the name,
or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At C:\Users\hao\Desktop\WOL main\Script.ps1:1 char:1 
+ Send-WOL -mac █████████████████ -ip █████████████
+ ~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (send-WOL:String) [], CommandNotFoundExeption
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundExeption

Press any key to continue . . .
```

even though when I put the exact same command within the script, manually into PowerShell it works perfectly.

Comment: PowerShell can't find `Send-WOL.ps1`, presumably because it's location is not in the PATH, or because you put the code from that script in your profile (which you told the batch file not to load).

Comment: Why use `-Command` instead of  `-File`? `@Powershell -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File %~dp0script.ps1`, _and use quotes around your path if it contains spaces_. If you want to use `-Command` then there's no need to use the `.ps1` file at all! `@Powershell -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command "Send-WOL -mac ------- -ip --------"`.

Comment: Try adding `Set-Location $PSScriptRoot` to your script.ps1 file

Answer (score 1):

With all the help I finally figure it out.

```
@ECHO OFF
powershell -executionpolicy bypass -file "---------------"
```

this is in the .bat file (replace the dashes with the path of the power shell script below)

```
function Send-WOL
{
<# 
  .SYNOPSIS  
    Send a WOL packet to a broadcast address
  .PARAMETER mac
   The MAC address of the device that need to wake up
  .PARAMETER ip
   The IP address where the WOL packet will be sent to
  .EXAMPLE 
   Send-WOL -mac 00:11:32:21:2D:11 -ip 192.168.8.255 
#>

[CmdletBinding()]
param(
 [Parameter(Mandatory=$True,Position=1)]
 [string]$mac,
[string]$ip="255.255.255.255", 
[int]$port=9
)
 $broadcast = [Net.IPAddress]::Parse($ip)

$mac=(($mac.replace(":","")).replace("-","")).replace(".","")
 $target=0,2,4,6,8,10 | % {[convert]::ToByte($mac.substring($_,2),16)}
$packet = (,[byte]255 * 6) + ($target * 16)

$UDPclient = new-Object System.Net.Sockets.UdpClient
$UDPclient.Connect($broadcast,$port)
[void]$UDPclient.Send($packet, 102) 

}

send-wol -mac ------ -ip --------
```

this is contained within the power shell script (replace the dashes with the mac and IP of the target computer)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the external script is located at C:\Downloads, Try this in your batch file:

```
Powershell -File "C:\Downloads\Send-WOL.ps1" -mac ------- -ip --------
```